# Getting error: "does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to following [this](http://oakdome.com/programming/MVC3_Simple_DBContext_Class.php) example but getting stuck to fetch data

I am getting error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'RMA.Models.RMAs' because 'RMA.Models.RMAs' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

Code Files Given below:

**RMAModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace RMA.Models
{
    public class RMAs
    {
        [Key]
        public int RNumber { get; set; }
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**DBContext Model.cs**

```
using System.Data.Entity; 
using RMA.Models;

namespace RMA.DAL
{
    public class DBContext_Model:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<RMAs> RMAs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ListController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RMA.DAL;
using RMA.Models;

namespace RMA.Controllers
{
    public class ListController : Controller
    {
        private DBContext_Model db = new DBContext_Model();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var items = db.RMAs;
            return View(items.ToList());
        }

    }
}
```

**index.cshtml**

```
@model RMA.Models.RMAs

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List of RMAs";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@foreach (RMA.Models.RMAs i in Model)
{
    <span>@i.OrderNumber</span>
}
```

**webconfig**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBContext_Model"
         connectionString="Server=xx\xx;Database=xxx;Integrated Security=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**I am using mvc3 Framework with .NET Framework 4 on VS2010**

Comment: I'd recommend you name the class "RMA" instead of "RMAs".  That plural is getting you into unnecessary trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your @model statement should be a list of RMAs (the name RMAs should probably be RMA; since each object represents a single RMA:

```
@model IEnumerable<RMA.Models.RMAs>
```